# Python map a value to each i-th sublist's element

Tags: python

I'm trying to do the following in python: given a list of lists and an integer i

```
input = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
i = 1
```

I need to obtain another list which has all 1s for the elements of the i-th list, 0 otherwise

```
output = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I wrote this code

```
output = []
for sublist in range(0, len(input)):
    for item in range(0, len(input[sublist])):
        output.append(1 if sublist == i else 0)
```

and it obviously works, but since I'm a newbie in python I suppose there's a better 'pythonic' way of doing this.

I thought using `map` could work, but I can't get the index of the list with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating extra variable to get index of current element in interation is quite unpythonic. Usual alternative is usage of [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) built-in function.

> Return an enumerate object. sequence must be a sequence, an iterator,
>   or some other object which supports iteration. The next() method of
>   the iterator returned by enumerate() returns a tuple containing a
>   count (from start which defaults to 0) and the values obtained from
>   iterating over sequence.

You may use list comprehension with double loop inside it for concise one liner:

```
input_seq = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
i = 1
o = [1 if idx == i else 0 for idx, l in enumerate(input_seq) for _ in l]
```

Alternatively,

```
o = [int(idx == i) for idx, l in enumerate(input_seq) for _ in l]
```

Underscore is just throwaway name, since in this case we don't care for actual values stored in input sublists.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a 1-liner, but it's not really obvious:

```
output = [int(j == i) for j, sublist in enumerate(input) for _ in sublist]
```

Somewhat more obvious:

```
output = []
for j, sublist in enumerate(input):
    output.extend([int(i == j)] * len(sublist))
```

Then "0 or 1?" is computed only once per sublist, which may or may not be more efficient.

Comment: Excellent answer as the other one. I wish I could split points. +1 to both though.